# bold line not covered in test class how to covered?

Tags: unit-test, community, account, contact

```
public class contactTriggerHandler {
    Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    public void performOnAfterInsert(List<Contact> lstCon){

        for (contact con : lstCon ) {  

            if(con.AccountId != null){
                AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);

                List<Account> AcctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
                List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: AccountIds GROUP BY AccountId];

                for (AggregateResult ar: cont){
                        Account acc = new Account(Id=(Id)ar.get('AccountId'), My_Contact__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
                        AcctToUpdate.add(acc);
                }
                update AcctToUpdate;
                system.debug('insertworking');
            }
         } 
    }


    public void performOnAfterUpdate(List<contact> lstcon, Map<Id, Contact> oldMapCon) {
    system.debug('!!enter');
        for (contact con : lstcon) {
                  if(con.AccountId!=null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId != null){
                        AccountIds.add(oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                        system.debug('@1-'+oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                  }


                  if(con.AccountId!=null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId != null && con.AccountId != oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId){
                       **AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);**
                       system.debug('@2-'+con.AccountId);
                        **AccountIds.add(oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);**
                        system.debug('@3-'+oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                   }


                  if(con.AccountId!=null && oldMapCon.get(con.Id).AccountId == null){
                        **AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);**
                        system.debug('@4-'+con.AccountId);
                  }

        List<Account> AcctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        List<AggregateResult> cont=[Select Count(Id) ContactCount, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: AccountIds GROUP BY AccountId];

        for(AggregateResult ar: cont){
            Account acc = new Account(Id=(Id)ar.get('AccountId'), My_Contact__c=(Integer)ar.get('ContactCount'));
            AcctToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
            update AcctToUpdate;
     } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to salesforce stackexchange. You should put more details on your question instead of just posting block of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to do two things: (a) change the account ID from one account to another, and (b) change the account ID from a valid account to nothing. Assuming you have a variable for your contact, you can do this:

```
someContact.AccountId = someNewAccount.Id;
update someContact;
// Validate behavior, then...
someContact.AccountId = null;
update someContact;
// Validate behavior
```